# Addition of Heroku custom buildpack has no effect

Tags: python, git, heroku, graphviz, buildpack

I am trying to make graphviz usable on Heroku, Python by adding repo from here https://github.com/mfenniak/heroku-buildpack-python-graphviz

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
```

But when I push:

```
git push heroku master

    Fetching repository, done.
    Everything up-to-date
```

It looks like I did nothing at all. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is failing because you haven't yet pushed new code -- if you add a new buildpack, you must push NEW code to your Heroku app in order for the new buildpack to be triggered.

To 'get around' this, just add a readme to your project, or change some whitespace -- then make a commit and push to Heroku.

Comment: Now it says 'Fetching custom git buildpack... done' but I still `Program dot not found in path.` when I try do use graphviz on the remote server. Can I somehow watch, where the buildpack was added to? What is the path to graphviz binaries?

Comment: Try this: run `heroku run bash` on the command line -- this will give you access to the Heroku dyno shell -- then look around the filesystem and see where the buildpack put the binaries.